# on virtual hosting, how to have a "mysql global event"-like function?

Tags: mysql, events, hosting, virtual, global

base on what I know, is nice to know mysql have **global event** surport since 5.1, *`but the fact of lots of virtual hosting company actually disable this function`* cause of "security reason" (as I know have fatcow.com & blue host.com is not allowing this function).

so I am looking for a **replacement method**, I have heard something about using php but how & will it run auto when I turn off my computer ? or I have to find a computer & just keep the php script is open & run. LOL

> I need a way that can auto run mysql command on virtual hosting's
>   server. please tell me any idea how can I do that on virtual hosting
>   company's server.

thanks for answering

Best regards.

Comment: btw, cron jobs is also not surport.